# Optimize the performance of a function

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, optimization

I created the following function below to merge the real values with the predicted values (when real are absent) in a new column in data.frame, the function actually works, but I would like to optimize it, because with the dataset that I work, the function takes about two hours to run .. If anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

```
p <-            
  function(object, newdata = NULL, type = c("link", "response", "terms"), 
           rse.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
           na.action = na.pass, ...)
  { 
{
    pred <- predict (object,newdata)    

      }

    vetor1 <- (newdata$ALT)         # Creates a column vector from the actual heights of the data.frame
    vetor1[is.na(vetor1)] <- 0      # Replaces the NA's present in the vector created above the numeric value 0
    vetor2 <- c(pred)           # Creates a vector from the predicted data
    for(i in 1:length(vetor1)){     # The loop is executed until all values vector1 pass the following condition
      if(vetor1[i]==0.00){      # If a value of the first vector has the value 0, ie, if it is absent
        vetor1[i]=vetor2[i]     # Then the predicted value will replace the missing value
        newdata$ALTMISTA <- vetor1  # The vector1, already possessing the actual values and the predicted values merged into the same vector goes                   on to become a new column in data.frame, this column is called a ALTMISTA
      }
    }
    return (newdata)            
  }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Questions about optimizing your code should be asked at [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @JohnOdom  Not necessarily.  We often consider (well-written :-) ) requests for code mods here, as there often turns out to be some existing libraries or R-packages which greatly speed up various data processing steps.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Oh okay, I guess I misunderstood the difference between the 2 pages, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts:  If you have a gigundo dataset, well, it's going to take time; or you'll need to learn to use the `parallel` package.

I don't think you want to re-define `newdata$ALTMISTA` every time thru the loop, as you're just overwriting the values.

You could remove the `i` loop by using a vectorized operation with `ifelse` :

```
 set.seed(1)
 foo<-sample(c(-1,1),10,rep=T)
 foo
 [1] -1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1
 bar<-11:20
 foo<- ifelse(foo<0, foo,bar)
 foo
 [1] -1 -1 13 14 -1 16 17 18 19 -1
```

But as I said, my suspicion is that you've got a large dataset and `predict` may well be the time-pig.  Try using  `Rprof` to find out where the time is spent.

Comment: Hello, I had tried something like that, but when I use the ifelse or while, for example, he can replace the missing values by predicted but "out of order". For example, the correct would be as follows:

actual values = c (1,5,6,0,0,4)
predicted values = c (2,4,6,3,5,4)
Final vector c = (1,5,6,3,5,4)

However, the final vector is as follows:

Final vector c = (1,5,6,2,4,4)                                     And that leaves the loop function is slow and not the prediction of values .. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't understand the manipulations in your comment. If you can post a small sample dataset, i.e.  `pred` and `newdata$ALT` , I can show you how to use `ifelse` to get the answer you desire.